# How to install npm packages within Google Dialogflow Fullfilment Inline Editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, package.json

I would like to install some npm packages into my chatbot but I cant make this working.

package.json file looks as below:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.5.x",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",
    "apiai": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

In index.js I have:

```
var jsonQuery = require('json-query');
```

The logs says:
dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded. Did you list all required modules in the package.json

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arrived because you didn't include package 'json-query'

run below command after all working fine.

```
npm install json-query
```

Comment: where do I write this command? I don't see any place where can I write such commands from the Inline Editor, are there any other way I can install the packages within the Dialogflow?

Comment: yes you can add ```json-query```  this package to your package.json file

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simpler than you would think (and @Dhaval mentioned it). You only have to include the name of the npm package in `package.json`:

```
{
"some": "crazyPropsFoo",
"engines": {},
"scripts": {},
"dependencies": {
  "actions-on-google": "^1.5.x",
  "firebase-admin": "~4.1.2",
  "firebase-functions": "~0.5",
  "npmpackage": "1.8.0",        //Here it is
  "apiai": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

Then `require` that package in your `index.js` file:

```
var PackageObj = require("npmpackage").PackageObject;
var yourVar = new PackageObj();
```